# Does the induced actions of a continuous map on the covering space determine it?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If I have continuous maps $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces  which induce the same actions of the fundamental group of X on the covering space of Y, are they necessarily homotopic?

Comment: If this were the case then all simply-connected spaces would be homotopy equivalent.

Comment: you're right, I phrased my question incorrectly